# Subtraction using changing values against a balance to find a single date value

Tags: sql, sql-server

As part of a larger report I am working on, I need to find the specific date a customer payment against the balance on their account will cause an over payment.  I have tried several approaches with no success, but here is the one I am currently trying to make work:

```
WITH [BalanceMath] AS (
SELECT number AS [Account], currentbalance AS [balance], paymentamount
FROM #PaymentInfo
GROUP BY number, currentbalance, paymentamount
UNION ALL
SELECT Account, balance - paymentamount, paymentamount
FROM [BalanceMath]
WHERE [balance] >= 0

)
SELECT * FROM [BalanceMath]
ORDER BY 1 asc, 2 desc
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)
GO
```

Important notes about the input:

- There are multiple accounts
- The payment amounts can vary from one payment to the next, most commonly as the final payment amount being different from the rest, so I do not have one consistent amount to use.  I need each payment considered separately.

Here is some of the output from my above query:

```
    Account balance   paymentamount
    123456  547.4906    115
    123456  547.4906    51.77
    123456  495.7206    51.77
    123456  443.9506    51.77
    123456  432.4906    115
    123456  392.1806    51.77
    123456  340.4106    51.77
    123456  317.4906    115
    123456  288.6406    51.77
    123456  236.8706    51.77
    123456  202.4906    115
    123456  185.1006    51.77
    123456  133.3306    51.77
    123456  87.4906     115
    123456  81.5606     51.77
    123456  29.7906     51.77
    123456  -21.9794    51.77
    123456  -27.5094    115
```

There are only 9 payments remaining on this account, but 18 rows are returned due to the differing payment amounts.  The problem becomes much worse when I try to include the info I really need, which is the payment date.  The row count then jumps to 48.  Here is how the data looks in the temp table I am pulling it from:

```
    ID      Account paymentdate paymentamount   currentbalance
    1080219 123456  3/25/2018   115             547.4906
    1080220 123456  4/25/2018   115             547.4906
    1080221 123456  5/25/2018   115             547.4906
    1080222 123456  6/25/2018   115             547.4906
    1080223 123456  7/25/2018   115             547.4906
    1080224 123456  8/25/2018   115             547.4906
    1080225 123456  9/25/2018   115             547.4906
    1080226 123456  10/25/2018  115             547.4906
    1080227 123456  11/25/2018  51.77           547.4906
```

Notes about the temp table data:

- This data resides across multiple tables, so I have gathered it into one table, but can easily have it separated into 2 tables if that would help with the query.
- currentbalance is the same on every row because the data was pulled from multiple tables, and we do not keep a running projection of the currentbalance diminishing with the payments, thus my attempt at a query here.
- I ultimately need the paymentdate for the payment that will send the customer's balance negative, but can use ID if necessary as each ID is uniquely tied to the payment date.
- The accounts in this temp table will for sure have an over payment.  I have already filtered them out from all other accounts.

A recursive query may not be the solution here, unless someone knows how to make it read each payment individually, so I am open to any suggestions on what I could try to achieve the desired outcome.  Thanks.

Comment: Just to check if I understood, in your temp table example you want to return row 1080223 and date 7/25/2018?

Comment: Yes @kirchner that is exactly correct.  I should have included that.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using some relatively recent version of SQL Server, you can try something like this:

```
WITH Balances1 AS
(
    SELECT *,
        CurrentBalance - SUM(PaymentAmmount) OVER (PARTITION BY Account ORDER BY PaymentDate, ID) AS Balance
    FROM #tt
)
, Balances2 AS
(
    SELECT *, ISNULL(LAG(Balance) OVER (PARTITION BY Account ORDER BY PaymentDate, ID), 0) AS Prev
    FROM Balances1
)
SELECT *
FROM Balances2
WHERE Balance < 0 AND Prev >= 0
```

The idea here is creating a running balance so we know what values are negative. That's in the first CTE `Balances1`.
The second one `Balances2` just puts the previous balance in the same row, so we can detect when the balance flips to negative.

And then the outer query does the filtering. Give it a try and lets us know if it Works and performs acceptably.

Comment: Thanks @kirchner  This is looking very promising.  My result set is slightly off what I expected (different number of accounts), so I need to spend some time reviewing the excluded accounts to see if they should or should not actually be included.  After that I'll know if this needs a little more tuning, or if somewhere else in my query does.  I'll post my result after I am done reviewing.

Comment: OK @kirchner I know what the problem is, but not necessarily the solution.  Your query works perfectly except when the very next payment is the one that sends the account into over payment.  I don't know if your query can be modified to properly account for this, I'll have to play with it a bit.  Otherwise, a potential work around for me since I already know which accounts will overpay is just to select the MIN(paymentdate) for any account that is not in the result set of your query.  You've been a big help, so thank you, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You mean when the first record in the temp table is the one you need? The query I suggested uses `LAG` function to look at the previous record so I never considered this possibility. Can you confirm my understanding in this comment is right? I think it might be an easy change.

Comment: It looks like the change needed is trivial if I understood correctly. I updated the answer. Added an `ISNULL` around `LAG`.

Comment: That fixed it.  Thank you so much!  I definitely need to read over LAG, LEAD and windowing again.  It is easy to forget about things you don't use regularly in queries.

Comment: Definitely do that. Windowing is an awesome feature. If I may suggest, Itzik Ben-Gan is a very good guy to read/listen/watch on this subject.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  I'll check him out for sure.